# What do you need to know to do the following integral

Tags: integration

Integrate $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos(\sqrt{2} x)e^{-x^2} dx$$

All i want to know is how to proceed. I have been stuck at this for a very long time now.

I tried writing the $\cos$ term as exponentials using Euler's formula and then to integrate the product term but I don't know how to integrate that either.

Comment: Does that square root extend over x, or just over the 2?

Comment: @enumaris just over 2

Comment: As this is a purely math question, this question might belong better on the math stack exchange.

Comment: by parts... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts

Comment: @JMLCarter i tried that. couldn't get anywhere. can you please show me how you would do it. i used wofram alpha on this integral and got √(π/e). i have no idea how to connect these two dots.

Comment: @enumaris the only reason i asked it here was because i got this question on a physics entrance exam. i assumed asking a physics person was the way to go. sorry if it caused inconvenience in any way.

Comment: Can you add your attempt or describe where you got stuck. The site has rules about homework like questions

Comment: @JMLCarter i too wanted to describe how i proceeded but i dont know how to type all that here. i am really new to this. i'll try to learn how to and edit my question as soon as i can. thanks

Comment: use Latex, for example as I edited into your post. More here https://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Or by rewriting the cosine using the Euler formula and then completing the square.

Comment: @UjjwalBarman I missed your part about already having used the Euler formula: The next step is to complete the square to write the exponentials as something like $e^{-(a+x)^2 + b}$ ($a$ will be complex) and then using the fact, that we can deform the integration path in the complex plane as long as we do not cross poles so that integrating over $e^{-(a+x)^2}$ is the same as integrating over $e^{-x^2}$ (from $-\infty$ to $\infty$).

Comment: @Sebastian Riese. thanks a looooooooottttttt. You're amazing. i got the answer. hey can you suggest a book so that i can better my integration skills. thanks again.

Comment: Only German ones (if that helps). But even so, I learnt most about integration from doing the exercises in the introductory maths and physics courses. So I can't point to a comprehensive source.

Comment: thanks. i'll try the same. Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 4):

All you need is the real part of 
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left[-\left(x^2-i\sqrt{2}x\right)\right]\,dx \stackrel{x\mapsto x+\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}}{=}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left[-\left(x^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]\,dx=\color{blue}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{e}}}.$$